# prove complex equation $\frac{d}{dt} \mathrm{arg} z(t)= \mathrm{Im}\frac{z'(t)}{z(t)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Im trying use ideas from this posts [Prove the identity $\frac{d}{dt} |z(t)|= |z(t)|Re \frac{z'(t)}{z(t)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1251897/prove-the-identity-fracddt-zt-ztre-fracztzt) , but im stopping at $\mathrm{Im}\frac{z'(t)}{z(t)}$. One hand, i got $\frac{x^2(t)}{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}$ $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}\right)$, but other hand $\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{y(t)}{x(t)}\right)$ * $\frac{i}{y(t)^2}$
thank you in advance

Comment: it's a bit unclear exactly what conditions, choices etc you have, but assuming $z(t)$ doesn't vanish, or at least near points where it doesn't vanish, you can write $\psi(t)=\log z(t)=\log |z(t)|+i \arg z(t)$ differentiable and then $z'/z(t)=\psi'(t)=(|z(t)|)'/|z(t)|+iarg'(z(t))$ and take real and imaginary parts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of $\frac{d}{dt} \tan^{-1} (\frac{y}{x}) = \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{y}{x})$ is fine, and is also legitimate when $z$ is in the first and fourth quadrants (i.e. when $x > 0$).

The error is in the right-hand side. It should look something like this:

$$\begin{eqnarray} Im\left(\frac{z'}{z}\right) & = & Im\left(\frac{x' + i y'}{x + iy} \right) \\
& = & Im\left(\frac{(x' + iy')(x - iy)}{(x + iy)(x - iy)} \right) \\
& = & Im\left(\frac{x'x + y'y + i(xy'-yx')}{x^2 + y^2} \right) \\
& = & \frac{xy' - yx'}{x^2 + y^2} \\
& = & \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} \frac{xy' - yx'}{x^2} \\
& = & \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2} \frac{d}{dt} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)
\end{eqnarray}$$

It looks like you made a mistake when realising the denominator of $\frac{x' + iy'}{x + iy}$.

Comment: Thanks for attention at my homework! I can see my mistake thanks to you!!!

Answer (score 2):

Since this involves $\operatorname{arg} z(t)$, let's do it in polar coordinates...
$$
z(t) = r(t)e^{i\theta(t)}
$$
where $r(t) = |z(t)|$ and $\theta(t) = \operatorname{arg} z(t)$ .
If we avoid points $t$ with $z(t) = 0$, then $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$ an be chosen continuous, and even [if $z(t)$ is differentiable] differentiable.
So
$$
z'(t) = r'(t)e^{i\theta(t)} + r(t)i\theta'(t)e^{i\theta(t)}
\\
\frac{z'(t)}{z(t)} = \frac{r'(t)e^{i\theta(t)}}{r(t)e^{i\theta(t)}} + 
\frac{r(t)\theta'(t)ie^{i\theta(t)}}{r(t)e^{i\theta(t)}}
=
\frac{r'(t)}{r(t)}
+i\theta'(t)
$$
But $r'(t)/r(t)$ and $\theta'(t)$ are both real, so
$$
\operatorname{Im}\frac{z'(t)}{z(t)} = \theta'(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\operatorname{arg} z(t) .
$$

Comment: Thanks you very much, comrade Teacher! But im understood, why my way was failure? In my opinion, arg z(t) = arctg(y/x). Takes derivative at arctg(y/x) and we get $\frac{x^2(t)}{x^2(t)+y^2(t)}$